# Keep user logged in in app even after the app closed using Async Storage

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to maintain a user as logged in, in an app even after the app closed, which means the user will no longer need to re-enter his/her userID and password again everytime he/she opens the app.

I want to achieve this using AsyncStorage (other than redux), my question is: is it possible to do so using AsyncStorage? I found sources online on how to persist data using Async but U could not connect those with what I wanted to do.

Comment: From [the web page](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html) it seems clear you *could* do this. Also that it wouldn't be a great idea (as it's unencrypted). What's your question, exactly?

Comment: to be exact is how to achieve maintaining user logged in in the app. For now my app requires user re-log in everytime i restarts the app.

Answer (score 3):

You should do it this way:

1. User opens the app, may be do this in you splash screen's `didMount` i prefer these kind of things to be done before hand in the splashsreen only. Check a flag in AsyncStorage say `isLoggedIn` if thats true, fetch
   user credentials from the AsyncStorage and fed them to your login
   request and the rest of the app flow continues.
2. If `isLoggedIn` is false (or null), show login screen to the user and upon successful login, save the credentials to AsyncStorage and on success must save the `isLoggedIn` flag to `true` and rest of the app flow continues.

For point 1, the code should look like:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn').then((value) => {
  if(value && value === 'YES') {
    //hit login api using the saved credentials and take user inside the application. 
  } else {
     //Take user to login page and progress with point 2.
  }
});
```

and below is the code that should work for point 2 upon success of login.

```
    const encrypted_username = myFancyEncrptionFunction(username);
    const encrypted_password = myFancyEncrptionFunction(username);
    AsyncStorage.setItem('username', encrypted_username).then(()=>{
      AsyncStorage.setItem('password', encrypted_username).then(()=>{
         AsyncStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', 'YES');
      });
    });
```

Its totally upto you how you want your user's credentials to be saved in AsyncStorage i.e. with or without encryption. But its always recommended to keep such things encrypted.

Comment: *"But its always recommended to keep such things encrypted."* Or better yet, not to keep them at all, but instead keep a single-use token (updated on next use) or similar.